# how to get load member list who has chatted with user A in PubNub

Tags: react-native, pubnub

Am trying to integrate the PubNub chat with react native, so I just using PubNub API for it.
I know that PubNub is mainly working with channels. so group chats there is no issue.
But using PubNub with one-to-one means how the channel will be created with both sides and the users should we connect at the same channel does direct channel will create the channel automatically or manually we have to create. 
how should I display profile pic and name for both users in the member's list for both sides because User A will see User B pic and User B will see user A pic in chatted History

Comment: This is more of a "how to write code" than a "my code isn't working" question which Stack Overflow will frown upon. But for some quick answers, a channel is what you want it to be: one-to-one, group, 1-to-many, whatever. Your server can generate a channel name using a UUID generator or whatever you like. How to get to users connected to talk 1-to-1 on the same channel is more of an app design question. If you have a real app you are working on, please reach out to PN directly to through support@pubnub.com with same questions above and someone can assist you.

Comment: If you contact PN support (support@pubnub.com), please include the link to this post, as well.

Comment: thanks for your response, the real problem is I need to get a Channels list for a particular user. To load on the channels List screen

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to learn about 1-1 chat architecture.

I recommend that you read [Inbound Channel Pattern](http://pubnub.github.io/pubnub-design-patterns/2015/03/05/Inbound-Channel-Pattern.html) post.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.